# Referring to a JSON element called "name" is returning an error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am trying to retrieve the field "name" from my JSON. My code is below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col, lit, last_day, current_date
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

jsonDF2 = jsonDF.withColumn('d', explode(col('d.results')))
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select(jsonDF2.d.externalCode.alias("CompanyCode"), jsonDF2.d.name)
```

CompanyCode returns perfectly fine however when I reference name which is a legit field name in the JSON I get:

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <bound method
> alias of Column<'d'>> of type <class 'method'>. For column literals,
> use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Is this because name is a reserved word? I've tried forcing `` jsonDF2.d.'`name`' `` or just `` '`name`' `` and get errors as well.

Assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select(
    F.col("d.externalCode").alias("CompanyCode"), 
    F.col("d.name")
)
```